# Directive elements as DOM siblings

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

### Why can't I add 2 directive elements to my page as siblings?

Example 1 (only 1 element shows):

```
 <p>
     <add-item type="widgeta" />
     <add-item type="widgeta" />
 </p>
```

Example 2 (both elements show):

```
<p>
    <span>
        <add-item type="widgeta" />
    </span>
    <span>
        <add-item type="widgetb" />
    </span>
</p>
```

My addItem directive template has 1 root level element:

```
<span>
    <a href="#" class="button"
       ng-cloak
       ...
       ng-class="{'disabled': !isInitialized}">{{getTitle(itemType)}}</a>
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="_addItem.chtml">
        ...
    </script>
</span>
```

Why do I need to wrap my directives in spans for them both to show?

Comment: Guess you wrote them incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks, Sherlock ;)

Comment: as you didnt provide any code - what else can I write? Your html is 100% ok :)